# STOP for a single campaign

Tags: twilio

I do not completely understand how to handle `STOP` messages if I have only one campaign. Should I respond with "... text 1" when I receive `STOP` or can I simply opt out the user without asking them to send '1'?

EDIT:

I am trying to implement message handling for a SMS short code to be compliant with the carrier requirements. https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/short-codes. Basically, to be compliant with the requirements, I have to handle specific SMS messages that I receive, in particular, `STOP` message that should opt out the number that sent it from my "campaign". A "campaign" is intuitively a series of SMS messages that I sent to users. [Here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/short-codes/what-are-the-requirements-for-short-code-help-and-stop-messages) is Twilio help entry that explains `STOP` messages.

I do not understand whether I have to ask the user to text me back `1` as the page suggests if I have no other choices. Can I just handle this `STOP` as I would do `STOPALL`?

Comment: to the downvoter: Please note that the twilio web site refers to stackoverflow for community help. Where else can I ask this "not about programnming" question?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a response that I received from Twilio support, in case someone else wants to ask this "non programming related" question:

"If you have one campaign, then you can opt them out the same way you would do a `STOPALL`."